# Is WinRT Pivot control dynamic binding possible?

Tags: windows-runtime, winjs, windows-phone-8.1

As the question says, can we bind items dynamically to a pivot control in WinRT? i.e. instead of static pivot items, I have varying number of pivot items.  We could do this in WP 7.5/8. I want to port my app to WinRT and stuck with this. I can't find any example on the net. So any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, can we do it in WinJS?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing that in WinJS using KnockoutJS, basically doing the bindings inside the WinJS control for each hub item.

Here's a nice walkthrough of the pivot on WinJS.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn615002.aspx